# How to edit my JSX filter and include an additional conditional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this mapping function that filters and sorts HTML items for me, for this case they sort items in a list.

Sometimes, the filter declares zero items pass the parameter check. When this happens, it would be idela for a specific HTML to show up:

`<span> no items pass the filter </span>`

However I'm not sure how to build that into my code:

Here is my original mapping function that filters and slices data for presenting. How can I add the conditional to my code below? Is there any way doing on doing so without having to deconstruct my function below?

```
                     <Grid item>
                            <List>
                                {data[2] && sortAll(data[3], 'desc', 'put_call_ratio')
                                    .filter((i) => i.ratio > 1.5)
                                    .slice(0, 4)
                                    .map((stock, index) => (
                                        <Grid>
                                        <ListItem>
                                            ...
                                        </ListItem>
                                        </Grid>
                                    ))
                                        }
                            </List>
                    </Grid>
```

The problem with this code above, is that when no items pass the filter, nothing displays.

Comment: The result of your filter call will be empty, use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an IIFE you can declare a variable for the array, then return it if it has a length, else the span:

```
<Grid item>
    <List>
        {(() => {
            const arr = data[2] && sortAll(data[3], 'desc', 'put_call_ratio')
                .filter((i) => i.ratio > 1.5)
                .slice(0, 4)
                .map((stock, index) => (
                    <Grid>
                        <ListItem>
                        </ListItem>
                    </Grid>
                ));
            return arr.length ? arr : <span> no items pass the filter </span>;
        })()}
    </List>
</Grid>
```

Unless the JSX for this component here is large, I'd prefer to declare the array beforehand, before rendering:

```
const arr = data[2] && sortAll(data[3], 'desc', 'put_call_ratio')
    .filter((i) => i.ratio > 1.5)
    .slice(0, 4)
    .map((stock, index) => (
        <Grid>
            <ListItem>
            </ListItem>
        </Grid>
    ));


return (
    <Grid item>
        <List>
            {arr.length ? arr : <span> no items pass the filter </span>}
        </List>
    </Grid>
);
```